# how to find and replace a string containing "/"

Tags: linux, find, replace

currently I have faced a problem in changing a string in a file which have `/` character . I want to replace `1/0` with `hetero` in a file. can you tell me which command to use ?

Comment: There are many ways to do this..can you add an example of your input file and your desired output from that..

Comment: is this some kind of home work ? replacing 1/0 or 0/1 with hetero ?

Comment: 0/1:32 0/0:43 0/2:56 1/1:100 1/0:10    this is the file .. now I want to change the 0/1 with hetero so the new file would be  0/1:32 0/0:43 0/2:56 1/1:100 hetero:10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`sed 's;1/0;hetero;g' my_filename`

Comment: this is showing the following error                                                           sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unterminated `s' command
bash: 1/0: No such file or directory
 No command 'hetero' found, did you mean:
 Command 'hetro' from package 'csound-utils' (universe)
hetero: command not found
g: command not found

Comment: @user163263 Are you sure you entered the above command including both single quotes? The error you indicated occurs if you omit the quotes.

Comment: I am sorry ... I have omitted the single quotes ... now it is working perfectly..Thank u so much .. but is there any way to replace the whole string with another string if they have have a common starting but different ending??

Comment: @user163263 Please provide an example for this.